# jQuery find out which element $(this) is actually a reference to

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, animation

Ok, I know what `$(this)` and `this` is towards what its actually meant. But a little project I am working on I am attempting to conform some dupe code I have into reusable functions.

With that I have a function that I want to animate a particular object under it in the same parent div. Which works, thats confirmed. However I have two events where I want this to be triggered from currently.

One is a loading event, that on `.ready()` I run an `$.each()` loop over the elements that match this requirement, and that works fine. To pass the element in question to the function I use

`$(this)` alone as is, as a parameter for the function, where the function takes that parameter and does with it according to the spec of this project. However where the problem is coming from is the second event I want to use to trigger this function with.

Which is a click based event on a per element basis. for that I have tried `.click()`, `.live()`, `.delegate()` of them `live()` seems to be the only thing that recognizes the object. I am currently stuck with jQuery 1.4.4 on this project. So `.on()` isn't available to me or I'd try that as well. I'm also confused why `delegate()` or `click()` wouldn't work and only `live()` will despite the elements rendering with the DOM but, thats a whole different thing from what I am looking for currently.

Bottom line is, the way I call to my function in this a working example via the loop mentioned prior:

```
$('.panels h3').each(function()
{
    accordionUpDown($(this), false);
});
```

and this click based example which doesn't work but one would assume it should but it doesn't.

```
$('.panels h3').live('click',function()
{
    accordionUpDown($(this), true);
});
```

also for reference here is the function itself:

```
function accordionUpDown(theElem, fx)
{
    //alert('test'+theElem);
    if(theElem.hasClass('active'))
    {
        var $elem = theElem.next('div');
        var elemY = ($elem.children('div').innerHeight()+2);

        if(fx == false)
        {
            $elem.addClass('active').css({height:elemY+'px'});
        }
        else
        {
            $elem.addClass('active').animate({height:elemY+'px'}, 2000);
        }
    }
    if(!theElem.hasClass('active'))
    {
        var $elem = theElem.next('div');
        var elemY = '0px';
        if(fx == false)
        {
            $elem.css({height:elemY}).removeClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            $elem.animate({height:elemY}, 2000).removeClass('active');
        }
    }
}
```

now to save those of you time, asking why don't I just use something like jQuery UI for the same effect, well simply put its a styling issue, along with some other functionality planned once this is in place properly. In either event custom needs is surpassing the easy concept.

Anyway, in the event of the click, Im starting to wonder if `$(this)` is somehow picking up the wrong thing, and if it is, then maybe its not working as expected cause of, so if thats the case, Im trying to figure out how I can find which element `$(this)` actually is

quick edit, for those who want to see it all, I have made a fiddle version.
http://jsfiddle.net/sDeq2/ that includes the HTML portion too

Comment: Put a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of `accordionUpDown`. Click on the H3 element. If the dev tools are open, code execution should be paused. Now, you can inspect which value was passed as the first argument.

Comment: If `.live()` works, then you're probably assigning the handler before the DOM is ready.

Comment: hmm, I don't tend to use live much. But are you saying I should have all my `live()` calls inside a `ready()`?

Comment: You said the `.live()` version is the one that works, right? Your question is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: @chris Generally, all your jQuery code should be inside a ready handler, as there is usually no point in running code before the DOM is ready. I use: `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: @IHateLazy admittedly going over my question again it kind of spun out of control from what I originally wanted to ask to what it is now. Overall I wanted to find out how I could find out what `[object Object]` was in the case of `$(this)` so I could figure out if that object is the right object I am assuming it is, then the question some how went from that to what I was actually doing currently which is basically the cause of why I wanted to know that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you print out the id or other identifiable attribute?

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Comment: I'm not using ID's currently, but that is a plausible solution to finding out what I need, I can add ID's to each H3 I am trying to ref, and see if it spits anything out, thanks for the idea

Comment: From the developer console you could also just enter the following and it should spit out an array of matching elements

    $('.panels h3')

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstood the initial methodology. I am going to have to propose that based on the description of the problems you have encountered (.live works but .click doesn't) that you are executing your code prior to the DOM actually being ready (inside an .ready() call).

All three of these event attachment scenarios work appropriately out of context.
http://jsfiddle.net/CsP2g/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someClass h3').click(function(){
        alert('fired click event that was bound to multiple items at once using .click()');
    });

    $('.someClass h3').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
          alert('fired click event that was bound to one item at a time using .each and .click()');
        });
    });

    $('.someClass h3').live("click", function(){
        alert('fired click event that was bound to multiple items at once using .live("click", func)');
    });
});
```

Comment: OP is using `live()` to attach the click handlers.

Comment: Misunderstood OP's methodology. Fixed per @Šime Vidas comment.